# Launch Program with Parameters

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-arguments

How do I write a very simple program that uses the command line to navigate to a program in the user's Program Files directory, then launches the `.exe` with a parameter? For example:

> "C:\etc\Program Files\ProgramFolder\Program.exe C:\etc\desktop\file.spp C\etc\desktop\file.txt"

This launches a program with a certain project file and a `.txt` file along with it.

Comment: I don't understand. All known desktop OS allow you to launch programs and pass command line arguments. Please, what is your question?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use the [ProcessStartInfo.Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to specify the string of arguments for your program:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();        
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\etc\Program Files\ProgramFolder\Program.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\etc\desktop\file.spp C:\etc\desktop\file.txt";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new text file, name it "go.cmd" and put the following in there:

```
"C:\etc\Program Files\ProgramFolder\Program.exe C:\etc\desktop\file.spp C\etc\desktop\file.txt"
```

Voila, you have your program!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass full executable path and parameters the program you need is the windows command prompt.

Comment: oh i'm sorry, seemed to have left out a big piece of information(sorry).

i need this program to prompt the user, asking what files they want to pass as parameters, then actually putting it into the command line